# ReactJs setState undefined when using react-autoBind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Getting this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined when trying to setState in a function. I'm aware that there are other similar issues already posted but none of them are using react-autobind

this works when I bind the function in the constructor Like so :

```
this.toggleNav = this.toggleNav.bind(this)
```

However I would like to accomplish this with react-autobind

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ScrollspyNav from "react-scrollspy-nav";
import autoBind from 'react-autobind';

export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  autoBind(this);

  this.state = {
    toggleMobileNav: false
  };

}

    toggleNav() {
      this.setState((prev, props) => {
        return {
            toggleMobileNav: !prev.toggleMobileNav
        }
      });
    }


render() {
    return(

        <ScrollspyNav
            scrollTargetIds={["page-top", "about", "projects", "signup"]}
            activeNavClass="is-active"
            scrollDuration="1000"
            headerBackground="false"
            activeNavClass="active-nav"
        >

            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
              <div className="container">
                <a id="page-top" className="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" onClick={this.toggleNav} type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  Menu &nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <div className= {this.state.toggleMobileNav ? "show collapse navbar-collapse" : " " + 'collapse navbar-collapse'} id="navbarResponsive">
                  <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li className="nav-item">
                      <a className="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                      <a className="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                      <a className="nav-link" href="#signup">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </ScrollspyNav>
)
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

If you use arrow function syntax to declare your method, you will not need to call `this.toggleNav = this.toggleNav.bind(this)` or use react-autobind

```
toggleNav = () => {
  this.setState((prev, props) => {
    return {
      toggleMobileNav: !prev.toggleMobileNav
    }
  });
}
```

Here's a Medium post that covers all the options: https://medium.com/komenco/react-autobinding-2261a1092849